# Who were the other Ravager captains?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy, guardians-of-the-galaxy-2

Although the current roster of the Guardians of the Galaxy (Star Lord, Gamora, Drax, Groot, Rocket) is taken from their current incarnation in the comics, Yondu (a Ravager captain in the MCU) is based on a character from the *first* Guardians of the Galaxy, from what is now called Earth-691.

Yondu is not the only Ravager captain; there were a number of other captains. There is one post-credit scene where a group of these captains were gathered together in a way very reminiscent of the Guardians themselves, implying that these characters being together was significant.

Do we know who these characters were, or at least who they were based on, and if there's any deeper meaning behind their appearance?

Comment: Guardians of the Galaxy beta release.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The group is made up of members of the [1975 version of the team](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Guardians_of_the_Galaxy_(Earth-691)) - either original or who joined at a later date. Yondu was one of the original members of the team.

- [Stakar Ogord aka Starhawk](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Stakar_Ogord_(Earth-691)), played by Sylvester Stallone
- [Martinex T'Naga](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Martinex_T%27Naga_(Earth-691)), voiced by Michael Rosenbaum
- [Charlie 27](https://marvel.com/universe/Charlie-27), played by Ving Rhames
- [Aleta Ogord, also aka Starhawk](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Aleta_Ogord_(Earth-691)), played by Michelle Yeoh
- [Krugarr](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Krugarr_(Earth-691))*
- [Mainframe](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Vision_(Earth-691)), voiced by Miley Cyrus

*Krugarr does not appear to have any credited actor behind him. Even in the [Facebook Live Q&A](https://www.facebook.com/jgunn/videos/10154241332796157/) Gunn did, he mentions the actors/actresses behind each of the captains, and does not mention anyone for Krugarr.

Comment: Dang, whoever played Krugarr is less than uncredited, I can't find anything on who played him. Obviously there isn't a proper actor to play him yet, because he isn't even voiced, but somebody must still have played him / provided mocap. Nothing online as to who that might be though.

Comment: Not necessarily. To my recollection, he doesn't even really move, just sorta standing there. If he was entirely CG, as he looked, adding a mo-cap actor would have been unnecessary cost/effort for what they did with him.

Comment: I read (in articles online, so naturally not gonna be 100% accurate) that he magics up some kind of symbol as a form of approval to Stakar's suggestion of getting back together. It's possible he's still just pure CGI, but I can't be sure without watching the scene again.

Comment: you forgot TAZERFACE!!!

Comment: Taserface was not in the mid-credits scene referred to.

Comment: @DisturbedNeo He did indeed do that.