# Who played Krugarr in Guardians of the Galaxy 2?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy, actors, guardians-of-the-galaxy-2

One of the many side-chararacters we see in Guardians of the Galaxy 2, is Krugarr.

[image: The redskinned alien Krugarr casting a spell]

But looking them up on Wikipedia and IMDB there's no actor listed.

Even previous questions here has failed to find out who Krugarr was played by: [Who were the other Ravager captains?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/158794/3804)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Krugarr is not played by anyone

[According to Cinema Blend](https://www.cinemablend.com/news/1654760/everything-you-need-to-know-about-that-other-guardians-of-the-galaxy-team), they're a purely CGI creation, without any recorded use of motion capture.

> Of all the original Guardians of the Galaxy team members introduced in Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2, **Krugarr was the only one who wasn't represented by a specific actor, as he remains an entirely CGI character for now.**

Comment: Where does it say that they didn't use mo-cap?

Comment: @valorum, how do you use mo-cap without an actor? If there's no actor, there can be no mo-cap.

Comment: Well, off the top of my head the animator could have mo-capped themselves. Or multiple people could have contributed to the motion capture. "*wasn't represented by a **specific** actor*" could indicate that multiple actors were involved.

Comment: @valorum I think they would become the defacto actor in that case. It's a good question though.